# Local fallback for jquery.js, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js incase CDNs are down or locall internet is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to provide a local fallback if the CDNs are down for jquery.js, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js.

With jQuery I can do

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"  integrity="" crossorigin=""></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/libraries/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

With bootstrap.css I can do using `onerror`

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.href='frameworks/bootstrap.min.css';" integrity="" crossorigin="" />
```

But when it comes to bootstrap.js the following does not work while I am using the same code as the above jQuery

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin=""></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="frameworks/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what do you want to achieve exactly, could you edit your question to be more clear with a runnable example?

Comment: maybe you want in the last example to do `window.bootstrap || ...` instead of `window.jQuery || ...` is that what you mean?

Comment: @Zac: Edited: Need to have local fallback if CDNs are down for jquery, bootstap.css and bootstap.js

Comment: in the bootstrap.js example you are checking `window.jQuery`, is that expected?

Comment: @Jawad you can use ServiceWorker to cache all three files

Comment: @Zac: window.bootstrap || ... solves the it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already have the answer for this but encase it helps:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.bootstrap) { 
        // if the bootstrap object is not present
        let bootstrapScript = document.createElement("script");
        bootstrapScript.setAttribute("src", "frameworks/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bootstrapScript);
    }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.href='frameworks/bootstrap.min.css';this.removeAttribute('integrity');this.removeAttribute('crossorigin');"
  integrity="" 
  crossorigin="" />
```

I hope this is useful still

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this for anybody using Django and wanting `{% static`.

This doesn't work. "Invalid escape character" in the Firefox console. And yet "view page source" looks fine. I guess the escaped double-quotes around the static invocation aren't escaped in the correct context.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.href=\"{%static 'wherever//bootstrap.min.css' %}\" ;"
  ...
```

However, this does work (and is more readable).

```
{%static 'wherever//bootstrap.min.css' as fallback %}
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.href='{{fallback}}' ;"
  ...
```